# Can I use a subjunctive after a superlative ?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, superlatifs

In this phrase I say "My brother is the sportiest in my family and he does weightlifting".

I have got "Mon frère est le plus sportif dans ma famille et il fait de la musculation".

Because of the superlative "le plus sportif", can I use a subjuctive version of "fait"?

Comment: "fait" is present, the subjunctive would be "fasse". The present is right in your sentence.

Comment: I don't think superlative has anything to do with subjunctive. It's just that superlative is often used with *que*, like in *c'est le plus sportif que je connais/connaisse* (both are correct).

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: No, you're fine with the indicative here.

---

**Long Answer** : Firstly, you only need* the subjunctive with a superlative when there's a *que* in there. For example, as Simon pointed out in the comments

> Il est le plus sportif *que* je connaisse

However, you might have noticed the star next to the need up there. That's because the subjunctive following a superlative is optional, depending on what you want to say. If you used the subjunctive, you're implying that he might be the most sporty, but you're not sure. Since in this case, you know your family and you are pretty sure he is the sportiest, you want to stick with the indicative. (Some better examples can be found in the link I gave below.)

---

If you want to read a bit more about it, simply googling "Subjuncitve after superlative french" will get you a wealth of reading, but [this](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/superlative-subjunctive/) website is always good for decent grammar explanations.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use a subjunctive here. Subjunctive is used to express a possibility, a wish or a desire. Here you are staying a fact, so indicative mode is required.